# Samsung Android stock browser image not displaying

Tags: android, css

I have a responsive slider that we've built to handle product images. The images are of varying sizes - most respect our target aspect ratio, but there are images that don't both landscape and portrait.

The slider works everywhere apart from on Samsung devices in the default Android browser. The experience is common to tablets and phones, but only Samsungs. It works fine on other Android devices, the litany of desktop browsers and iOS.

The problem seems to boil down to a height: 100%; on the image which is used to limit portrait images to the height of the container. I've redacted our code down to the simplest version in the JSFiddle below.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g453xstc/8/

```
ul {
    position: relative;

    /* height 0 and padding top to maintain aspect ratio when resized */
    height: 0;
    padding: 75% 0 0;
}

li {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    /* background to demonstrate how far the layout works on Samsungs */
    background: #eee;

    /* absolute positioning to account for height: 0 */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

img {
    height: 100%; /* the offending line */
    width: auto;
}
```